# What are the two different types of google search results called?

Tags: google, search-results, sitelinks

### Google SERPs have search results that appear in two different ways:

[image: Single Search Result]
**Single Search Result**

[image: Single Search Result with Sitelinks]
**Single Search Result with [Sitelinks](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334&topic=2370570&ctx=topic)**

Are there official terms for these?  I know that a "SERP" is Search Results Page, and I'm fairly certain that a single search result is just called a "search result".  But what is a search result with [Sitelinks](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334&topic=2370570&ctx=topic) called?

Comment: I thought it was just called a search result with sitelinks. I don't think it has any special name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know the official term is just sitelinks. That's what google calls them: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=8523&answer=47334. Also, here is a good article on the topic and they are called sitelinks as well. http://www.click-finders.com/blog/how-to-get-google-sitelinks-on-your-serp-listing/

Answer (score 0):

It's really just called "search result" (the "bundle" without the sitelinks). The sitelinks are a nice feature, a quick introduction to important pages or categories of a site, if the algorithm worked well, but more an addon to the actual search result (you don't search for sitelinks, you search for results - pages).

What's more important is that there is much more than just site links that is "blended" into or is part of the search result, the concept of "Universal Search". Here is a nice summary [on Search Engine Land](http://searchengineland.com/google-20-google-universal-search-11232) about it. A lot of assets compete for attention, like images, videos, local information, news - and lately author images of the social web.

Which is nice, because being the number one is not so important anymore.